# Change connection pooling type in grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, database-connection, connection-pooling, c3p0

I need to change the connection pooling type in my grails application to c3p0. I have searched through the net and also into stack overflow but could not find adequate resources.

I know that I need to create a new datasouce in resources.groovy and override the existing datasource. But I am now aware exactly how I am supposed to do it.

Can anyone help me out with it. It is a kind request to please provide me step by step guidance for this rather that providing some link which I can refer. I have already referred number of links and have been unable to makeout anything from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try theese solutions, has samples and a step by step guidance in a blog.

[How do I configure c3p0 for a grails 2.X application with multiple datasources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532003/how-do-i-configure-c3p0-for-a-grails-2-x-application-with-multiple-datasources)

[Configuring Grails to use own DataSource implementation or to proxy the standard DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404255/configuring-grails-to-use-own-datasource-implementation-or-to-proxy-the-standard)