# Defining an alternate connection pool in Grails 2.3.6

Tags: grails, connection-pooling, bonecp, hikaricp

I know that, at some point between Grails 1.X and Grails 2.X, the default connection pooling library changed from `commons-dbcp` to `tomcat-dbcp`.

Now, I'm trying to configure either BoneCP or HikariCP as the connection pooling library for my Grails application.

However, I see that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404255/configuring-grails-to-use-own-datasource-implementation-or-to-proxy-the-standard) offers a solution which might only apply to Grails 1.X.

I also found [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/allnightlong/929543), but again, I don't know which Grails version it applies to.

So, is it possible to define a custom connection pool inside a Grails 2.3.6 application? Thanks!

Comment: That Gist should work for any version of Grails.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore True, but it should probably be updated to utilize `grails.util.Holders` in lieu of the deprecated individual Holder classes.

Comment: @rmlan Agreed, but the approach is still the same.

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE:** OK so you actually need to tell Grails **not** to pool the datasources, since HikariCP is now taking care of this.

I saw connection weirdness in my apps if I left that switch on. So instead say:

```
pooled = false
```

OK yeah, @Joshua Moore is right.

I tried doing it with updated Grails methods and this is the relevant section of my `resources.groovy` file. As far as I can understand, the configuration values in `Datasource.groovy` are pulled into `resources.groovy` at runtime, after the target runtime environment has been identified (`development`, `test` or `production`).

```
def config = Holders.config
def dataSources = config.findAll {
  it.key.toString().contains("dataSource_")
}

dataSources.each { key, value ->
  def ds = value
  "${key}"(HikariDataSource, { bean ->

     def hp = new Properties()
     hp.username = ds.username
     hp.password = ds.password
     hp.connectionTimeout = 6000
     hp.maximumPoolSize = 60
     hp.jdbcUrl = ds.url
     hp.driverClassName = ds.driverClassName

     HikariConfig hc = new HikariConfig(hp)
     bean.constructorArgs = [hc]
  })
}
```

And this is the relevant section of my `DataSource.groovy` configuration:

```
// environment specific settings
environments {
   development {
      dataSource_myapp1 {
         pooled = false
         username = "CONFIGURE_ME_EXTERNALLY"
         password = "CONFIGURE_ME_EXTERNALLY"
         driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
         dialect = 'org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect'
         url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@MYDBHOST1:1521/MYSERVICEID1'
      }
      dataSource_myApp2 {
         pooled = false
         username = "CONFIGURE_ME_EXTERNALLY"
         password = "CONFIGURE_ME_EXTERNALLY"
         driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
         dialect = 'org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect'
         url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@MYDBHOST2:1521/MYSERVICEID2'
      }
   }
}
```

In my case, it's pretty much the same for `test` and `production` environments. Thanks!

Comment: How are you loading the Oracle driver? I get an error when using this method. It seems that the Oracle driver is not loaded by the time the app gets to the resources.groovy running. 2016-02-19 09:07:10,767 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  util.DriverDataSource  - Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.

Comment: Another error in the stack trace: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Exception during pool initialization: HikariPool-0 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 6002ms.